# Using server variable LOGON_USER to identify a user?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm converting from my own method of account handling procedures to windows authentication. I have an Account table in my DB with a Username column. I'm thinking of using

> Request.ServerVariable["LOGON_USER"]

and passing it to the Account Username column at the time the user creates an account. On my account page, I want to display the current user's information.  When querying Account, is it safe for me to use Username as an identity? Could a user deviously change their identity to view different accounts?

Comment: Yes, you could do that.  Note: The LOGON_USER variable can be faked from the client.  A proxy tool like Fiddler can do that.

Comment: Is there a better way to do it? Maybe connect my SQL database accounts to windows authentication accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Added a SqlMembershipProvider schema to the DB and am going to access account data using that.